React Native FontAwesomeIcon not working in TouchableHighlight or Pressable
I cannot put any Font-Awesome Icons inside of TouchableHighlights or Pressable elements.
<TouchableHighlight onPress={someOnPressMethod}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} color='white'/>
</TouchableHighlight>

If I do so the following error occurs:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
This error is located at:
    in FontAwesomeIcon (created by Page)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by TouchableHighlight)
    in TouchableHighlight (created by TouchableHighlight)
    in TouchableHighlight (created by Page)
...

I can add the Icon outside of the TouchableHighlight just fine.
I am thankful for any help!

Use style property instead.
<TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} style={{color: 'red'}}/>
</TouchableHighlight>


I guess all FontAwesomeIcons have to be put into Text elements.
If i wrap the Icon around a Text element it works just fine
<TouchableHighlight onPress={someOnPressMethod}>
    <Text><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} color='white'/></Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

